# Find test(a1,a2,a3...) and replace it with test(a[1],a[2],a[3]...) in a file

Tags: awk, sed

The file has the following lines:

```
test(a1,a2,a3....)
```

The number of elements inside the `test()` could vary. We have to replace it with

```
test(a[1],a[2],a[3],....)
```

Sometimes, it could have multiple test statements in the file:

```
test(x1,x2,x3)
test(b1,b2,b3)
```

We must replace the elements within `test()`.

Example output for this would be:

```
test(x[1],x[2],x[3])
test(b[1],b[2],b[3])
```

The rest of the test file should stay intact. Only the keyword `test` should be searched for, and replaced as above.

Input:

```
test(a1,a2,a3)
```

Output:

```
test(a[1],a[2],a[3])
```

Comment: Edit your question to include concise, testable, sample input and expected output along with whatever you have tried so far. Include in your input examples where the pattern you want to replace includes blank chars, newlines, or anything else you think would be hard for a tool to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
cat $INPUT_FILE \
| sed -e 's/test($/test( /' \
    -e 's/test(\([^)]*\))/test(\
\1\
)/g' \
| sed -e '/test($/{
    :Loop;
    h;
    s/^.*$//;
    N;
    s/\([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_]*\)\([0-9][0-9]*\)/\1[\2]/g;
    N;
    H;
    x;
    s/\n//g;
    /test($/ b Loop;
}' \
    -e 's/test( $/test(/'
```

With this input:

```
nothing
nothing
test(b,c,d)
test(a1,a2,a3) test(x1,y2,z3) foo test(b1,b3,b4)
foo test(a1, a2, a3) bar
foo test bar
test()
test(
a1, a2, a3
)
```

Produces this output. Note the last case - I don't handle split lines.

```
nothing
nothing
test(b,c,d)
test(a[1],a[2],a[3]) test(x[1],y[2],z[3]) foo test(b[1],b[3],b[4])
foo test(a[1], a[2], a[3]) bar
foo test bar
test()
test(
a1, a2, a3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't it be easier just to restrict substitution on lines that match the pattern `test(..)`

It can done in this way:

```
$ cat file1
abcd
test(x,y,z)
test(a1,a2,a3) test(a1,a2,a3) hello 
test(a1,a3,a5)
abc test(a1, a2, a3) efgh
abcde test bar
test()
test(
a1, a2, a3
)
test() test(a45, b67,c67, he7)
$ sed -r '/test\(([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+,?\s*)*\)/ s/([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)(,?)(\s*)/\1\[\2\]\3\4/g' file1
abcd
test(x,y,z)
test(a[1],a[2],a[3]) test(a[1],a[2],a[3]) hello 
test(a[1],a[3],a[5])
abc test(a[1], a[2], a[3]) efgh
abcde test bar
test()
test(
a1, a2, a3
)
test() test(a[45], b[67],c[67], he[7])
$
```